# The physics of breaking eggs

Tags: resource-recommendations, everyday-life, home-experiment

I have to to write an  4000 word research paper for my IB diploma in high school. It is called the extended essay. I was thinking about writing on the physics of breaking eggs. I came up with the idea that their might be some experiments I could do and find the best way to crack an egg. I'm having trouble finding sources. I think I need help with some directions I could take this topic as I find it very interesting.

Comment: Have you tried http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=egg+cracking+physics&btnG=&hl=es&as_sdt=0%2C5 ? I find that any study would be quite useless, practice is way better than anything physics can say.

Comment: @jinawee Would all the references you find there be publicly accessible for high school students?

Comment: Most if them, no. You have to pay or contact some university.

Answer (score 0):

I think jinawee's list (among the comments) is a great starting point. There was one interesting series of experiments that I didn't find in that list (at least not in the first 5 pages of the list that I looked through), which were reported in [this PRL paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.93.035504). (If you don't have access to PRL, check out the [arXiv version](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0402461).) What might make this series of experiments especially useful for a starting point for an IB extended essay, is that the experiment was very easy with well recorded results: they drilled small holes in the top and bottom of the eggs, blew their contents out, and dried them; then placed each egg inside a large, sealed plastic bag and catapulted it against the ground and then recorded the sizes of the fragments. You might then compare your results with theirs.

There was also a great media coverage of this series of experiments: see a great description and videos among the [APS focus stories](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevFocus.14.5) (and here are shorter descriptions in [Nature News](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/news040223-11) and in [the Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/science/2004/mar/04/improbableresearch.science)).